# Pine Script : Entering after x consecutive Green Bars / Candles

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

I am trying to enter a strategy after "X" consecutive bars.

```
greenCandle = barstate.isconfirmed and (close > open)
G = input(11, minval=1)

strategy.entry("buy", true, 1, when = greenCandle[G] and close[0]>open[0])
```

This gives me an entry 11 bars after the green but does not give me an entry after 11 consecutive greens.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to count consecutive events is to use `math.sum()`.

> math.sum(source, length) → series float

Pass `your_condition ? 1 : 0` as source so it would add 1 to the count if your condition is `true` and add 0 otherwise. Then compare this sum with your desired target count.

```
//@version=5
strategy("My script", overlay=true, process_orders_on_close=true)

in_cnt_long = input.int(5, "Consecutive long event count")
in_cnt_short = input.int(3, "Consecutive short event count")

is_green_candle = (close >= open)
is_red_candle = (not is_green_candle)

green_candle_cons_cnt = math.sum(is_green_candle ? 1 : 0, in_cnt_long)  // Sum the number of candles where is_green_candle was true over the lookback period 
cons_green_cond = (green_candle_cons_cnt == in_cnt_long)                // Check if the consecutive count is equal to your target

red_candle_cons_cnt = math.sum(is_red_candle ? 1 : 0, in_cnt_short)     // Sum the number of candles where is_red_candle was true over the lookback period 
cons_red_cond = (red_candle_cons_cnt == in_cnt_short)                   // Check if the consecutive count is equal to your target

if (cons_green_cond)
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)

if (cons_red_cond)
    strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'd code it that way:

```
//@version=5
x = input.int(11)
red = close < open                       //red bar condition
count = ta.barssince(red)                //count of bars since red

if barstate.isconfirmed and count == x   //evaluates whether barstate is confirmed and count is equal to the given x
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long) //Enter Long
```

Comment: Thanks I tried the below but it comes up with the error:

"Mismatched input 'strategy.entry' expecting 'end of line without line continuation'."

Code:



//@version=5
strategy("GHa3", overlay=true)
x = input.int(11)
red = close < open                       //red bar condition
count = ta.barssince(red)                //count of bars since red

if barstate.isconfirmed and count == x   //evaluates whether barstate is confirmed and count is equal to the given x
   strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long) //Enter Long

Comment: This is difficult to explain for me with word, so just look at this [picture](https://prnt.sc/ZKRbxJ7jgBw5)... the problem is the number of spaces.

Comment: I edited the code above, so you should be able to copy it, which should work right away

Comment: Thanks, really appreciate your help. It now comes with the error "Could not find function or function reference 'input.int'."

Comment: oh okay, then you are not on version 5 of pine script. just use `input()`

Answer (score 1):

Answer provided first by vitruvius.
Personally, I simply prefer using simple functions.

```
//@version=5
strategy("Example", overlay = true, process_orders_on_close = true)

//#region -------------------------- INPUT

i_bullLookback  = input.int(5, 'Bullish Lookback', inline = '', group = 'Max History', minval = 1)
i_bearLookback  = input.int(3, 'Bearish Lookback', inline = '', group = 'Max History', minval = 1)


//#region ---------------------- FUNCTIONS

// @function                      when a defnied condition is met, count consecutive candles until a given number is reached and returns true as its done.
// @param condition               (series bool) provided condtion(s). Here: bullCondition/bearCondition.
// @param lookback                (simple int)  user input 
// @returns                       (simple bool) true/false
// Dependencies                   user input.
checkCondition(series bool _condition, simple int _lookback) =>
    count  = math.sum(_condition ? 1 : 0, _lookback)
    count == _lookback ? 1 : 0


//#region ------------------- DECLARATIONS

bool    bullCondition   = close >= open
bool    bearCondition   = not bullCondition

// function call
bool    longCondition   = checkCondition(bullCondition, i_bullLookback)
bool    shortCondition  = checkCondition(bearCondition, i_bearLookback)


//#region --------------------- STRATEGIES

switch 
    longCondition   => 
        strategy.entry("Long ID", strategy.long)
        // add more logic as needed

    shortCondition  => 
        strategy.entry("Short ID", strategy.short)
        // add more logic as needed
```